# Well founded tree of height $\omega$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Can someone provide an example of a well-founded tree of height $\omega$. It seems like this would not be possible, as having height $\omega$ would yield an infinite sequence.

Comment: The height is the supremum of the lengths of the paths, not the length of the longest path. You can make a well founded tree with arbitrarily long finite paths.

Comment: @Carl Mummert So $T = \{ \emptyset, \langle 1 \rangle, \langle 1, 1 \rangle, \langle 2 \rangle, \langle 2, 2 \rangle, \langle 2, 2 , 2\rangle ,  \langle 3 \rangle , \langle 3,3 \rangle, \langle 3,3, 3 \rangle,  \langle 3,3, 3, 3 \rangle, ..... \}$ would be an example. Right?

Comment: @Carl Mummert Thanks!